# Can i Integrate mysql and sql server databases to view them on sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, scom

i have installed mysql and MSSQLSERVER on my windows server 2012  i need to monitor them using system center operations manager 2012 sp1.
now am able to monitor sql server but not the mysql server so can i integrate mysql and microsoft sql server so that i can get all the databases in the mysql  as in the sql server. how can i achieve  this? is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to be able to monitor a MySQL Database you must have a proper Management Pack Imported into SCOM. [Bridgeways](https://bridgeways.com/) offers such a [Management Pack](https://bridgeways.com/products/mysql-monitoring-reporting), but it is not free. As today, Microsoft has not yet released a MP for MySQL.